# Testing that disk is parked

Tags: zsh, hard-disk, proc

I run a command in zsh's `preexec()`, i.e. before every other command entered and accepted for run. Would like to skip doing this when I detect that the disk of current `$PWD` is parked. Can I do proper detection via /proc file system or other method?